# CSS can hide span-element and show it on hover, does not work for p-element

Tags: html, css

I want to offer a selection by radio buttons. Upon hovering over the label for the button, I want there to appear an explanation for that option.
I can achieve this by putting the explanation text into a span-element, but not in a p-element...and I fail to understand the difference:

```
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Select player</h2>
        <div clas="radios">
            <legend>Select character class:</legend>
            <p class="row">
                <input type="radio" id="character-ninja" name="character" value="ninja">
                <label for="character-ninja" class="show">Ninja</label>
                <p class="hidden">The ninja class....</p> 
            </p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

with the style sheet

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}

.show:hover + .hidden{
    display: block;
}
```

The text in the p-element is hidden by "display:none", but it does not appear upon hovering over the text in the label-element.
If I change the p-element into a span-element, the text is also hidden by "display:none", but it **does** appear upon hovering over the text in the label-element.

I think that the different behavior might be the result of nesting a p-element within a p-element...but even so I don't quite understand why it is "partially working", as I would call it.

Comment: See the tag omission explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) for the `p` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `div` as a row element:

`<div class="row">`

The reason why nested `p` tags does not work in your code is that it is not valid HTML. It is corrected by the browser. So the sibling of `label` is no longer `p` then.

```css
.hidden{
    display: none;
}

.show:hover + .hidden{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
  <fieldset>
      <h2>Select player</h2>
      <div clas="radios">
          <legend>Select character class:</legend>
          <div class="row">
              <input type="radio" id="character-ninja" name="character" value="ninja">
              <label for="character-ninja" class="show">Ninja</label>
              <p class="hidden">The ninja class....</p> 
          </div>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: thanks for your expanation about the destroyed sibling relation, ...I failed to understand what exactly happened with a p-element inside a p element (should have looked at the source code in the brwoser though...).